# Trigger plugin event on entity save

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

In Dynamics CRM 2011, I have an entity (Quote).

My problem, it's impossible to trigger an event during form saving in order to complete some actions. (Work on a new entity 'Create', but 'Update' with an existing entity doesn't work)

(ie: Send email based on calculs).

I tried with all type of "Message" and "pipeline stage" but nothing is triggered.

Some ideas to help me ?

Edit:

I throw an exception to know if is triggered, like this

```
  protected void ExecutePreDevisUpdate(LocalPluginContext localContext)
    {
        if (localContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("localContext");
        }
        throw new Exception("prédevis");
        // TODO: Implement your custom Plug-in business logic.
    }
```

Comment: Have you used `\sdk\bin\PluginRegistrationTool.Exe` to make sure your Plugin is registered correctly. I do not trust the Developer Toolkit for anything and my personal recommendation is to dump it.

Comment: Can you post the full code for your plugin? That method does not match the required method for IPlugin so there must be more.

Comment: @mbreton just fyi but depending on the email you are sending, you may be able to use a workflow

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried attaching to the w3wp.exe service on the server and putting a breakpoint at the start of your execute method?

You will need to install the remote debugger on your server.

Answer (score 0):

Just like @Nicknow said, you should download the crm 2011 SDK and use the pluginregistrationtool.exe. You don't have to run it on the crm server if that helps.

That being said, without source code or an error message, I would assume that the plugin's         `FilteringAttributes` aren't set properly.

When you register the plugin to update, you need to specify the entity fields being updated that it must run on. The plugin runs only when these fields are updated.

You can view these configuration settings in multiple ways, but the Plugin Registration Tool is a sure thing. Here is a walkthrough in msdn with it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309580.aspx

Hope this helps.